# Accessing PHP script files outside site directory using path relative to root

Tags: php, navigation, root

I'm using apahce server and I have files that I want to keep private. I've read that they should be put in a directory outside of the document root. 
I could access them from the root directory using:

```
<?php include('../includes/somefile.php');?>
```

To simplify navigation I want to use paths relative to the root. This works fine for directories within the site such as:

```
define('ROOT_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
include(ROOT_PATH.'/path/file.php');
```

but I get errors when I try going up the directory tree like this:

```
include(ROOT_PATH.'../includes/somefile.php');
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `..` is taking to the previous directory of the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` which you do not have permission to access.